# Issue with bean from another JAR

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, jar

I'm exporting a JAR that contains a class:

```
public class SerializerHelper {
    public String toJson(final Object src) {...}
}
```

And the trialApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="serializerHelper" class="com.trial.SerializerHelper"/>

</beans>
```

Then, I'm importing that JAR on another project, and on its applicationContext.xml I'm importing the trial context as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Replace all @Autowired by its instances -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <import resource="classpath*:trialApplicationContext"/>

    <bean id="booksSerializer" class="com.trial.BooksSerializerImpl" />
    ...

</beans>
```

And then, I'm using that bean on my class as:

```
public interface BooksSerializer {
    String getBooks();
}

public class BooksSerializerImpl implements BooksSerializer {

    @Autowired
    private SerializerHelper serializerHelper;

    ...

}
```

However, the code is failing with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksSerializer' defined in URL [...applicationContext.xml]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.trial.BooksSerializerImpl] for autowiring metadata: could not find class that it depends on
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksSerializer' defined in URL [jar:file:/....jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.trial.BooksSerializerImpl] for autowiring metadata: could not find class that it depends on
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksSerializer' defined in URL [jar:file:/....jar!/applicationContext]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.trial.BooksSerializerImpl] for autowiring metadata: could not find class that it depends on
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:136)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productSerializer' defined in URL [jar:file:/....jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.trial.BooksSerializerImpl] for autowiring metadata: could not find class that it depends on
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:136)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>     Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksSerializer' defined in URL [jar:file:/....jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.trial.BooksSerializerImpl] for autowiring metadata: could not find class that it depends on]]

This error is happening when I'm trying to run my project on a jersey server.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is your `BooksSerializer` interface? Did you put any annotation on that interface ?

Comment: No, the interface has no annotations.

Comment: Annotate your `BooksSerializer` interface with `@Service` and let me know the status.

Comment: I've tried it, but, unfortunately,  nothing changes

Comment: Did you use  `<mvc:component-scan ="package">`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't use it, I've added: <mvc:component-scan base-package="com.jartrial, com.trial" /> into the applicationContext.xml. com.jartrial is the package where SerializerHelper is defined (the one that I'm importing as a jar), and com.trial is the package where I'm using it (the one where BooksSerializer is defined). But it's still not working :(

Comment: Use `<context:component-scan base-package="com.jartrial.*, com.trial.*" />` instead of mvc tag.

Comment: It is working fine now! Thank you so much!! If you add your last comment as an answer I will mark it as the right answer and upvote it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @FVod, happy to help. I put my answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use context component scan for scanning your package, so that your declare spring bean can be discoverable by spring container.
Declare it in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jartrial.*, com.trial.*" />
```